# WP Search page only displaying keyword searched, no results

Tags: wordpress, search

I'm going nuts here. I'm new to WP, but have read tons of the codex and many WP development books, that I feel I have a decent understanding of how the codes work. So far I have been able to troubleshoot every issue I have come across creating a custom theme simply by searching the web for answers. I've not this particular question, though some related. I've tried the recommended methods, but for my situation, they are not helping.

Here's the issue.

I have a customized search bar in the top right corner of my header.

I have included the  `get_search_form()`

I used the correct code, but stack overflow keeps blocking it so I just used a short demo of the php get search form code for this questions purpose to display the customized search form which I made.

Everything works fabulously until the search results are displayed via the search-`page.php` I created. When you do a keyword search, the only thing displayed is:

```
Search Results For: "whatever you enter into the search box".
```

I'm focusing on the two php files in order to make my search work.

Below is the code for each.

**search-form.php**

```
<form method="get" class="has-form" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">
<div class="row collapse">
<div class="large-8 small-9 columns">
<label class="hidden" for="s"><?php _e('Search:'); ?></label>
<input type="text" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" />

<input type="hidden" value="post" name="post_type" id="post_type" />

</div>
<div class="large-4 small-3 columns">
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

As well as `search-page.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Search Results pages.
 */

get_header(); ?>


    <section id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header">
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'shape' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->

            <?php shape_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'search' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php shape_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'search' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- #content .site-content -->
    </section><!-- #primary .content-area -->
```

Can someone please help me figuring out why when a search is done it only shows what was searched for with no results. I have about 6 test posts up and not even the keyword "the", "lorem", or "hello" are displaying results other than what word was searched for.

Am I missing a chunk of code? I retrieved the code I have and tweaked it just a bit to fit my theme's design, but nothing major... just class names.

Thanks in advance.

Also, here is a screenshot to demonstrate what I am talking about.

[image]